# How to place a fixed div above twitter bootstrap nav menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to place a div above a twitter bootstrap navigation menu, *Intro* is the div that I want to display above the menu which must be fixed. The issue is I have placed a background image on the menu, but it shows the background image on the *Intro* div as well, I want to display the background image after the *Intro* div. Please help me solve this issue.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div id="Intro">
 This is page is created with bootstrap
</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="home.aspx"> Home</a> </li>
     <li><a href="contact.aspx"> Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

.navbar-inverse { 
   background-color : #fffff;
   border-color:transparent;
   background: #ffffff;
   url('bgimg.gif') repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Move `<div id="Intro">`above the navbar code:

```
<div id="Intro">
This is page is created with bootstrap
</div>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
```

Add some space on top of navbar-fixed:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
  top: 20px;
```

Make this size the height you want for  `<div id="Intro">`

Add additional styling to  `<div id="Intro">`

```
#Intro {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
```

**EDITED:**
Additional styling for intro div. Add some dimensions and background color to intro div. Try this :

```
 #Intro {
     top: 0;
     position: fixed;
     background-color: #fff;
     height: 40px;
     width: 100%;

  }
```

Comment: Thanks moodyjive.. I tried the above and it is working but when i scroll the webpage the scroll content is visible inside the Intro div i.e. fixed.I do not want to make visible scrolling content inside Intro div. How can i achieve this...

Comment: This is great, but how to scroll this Intro div so that only the navbar sticks to the top when the page is scrolled.